# How to access R.java programmatically?

Tags: android

How to access `R.java` programmatically?
I know the path to `R.java` class on the C: drive
but I want to access it programmatically in Android, can I access `R.java` using either `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` or `openFileInput`?

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I access R.java using either of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() or openFileInput ?

No.

`R.java` is a source file, written in a programming language called Java. Java is a compiled language; the source code to `R.java` is compiled as part of building your app. The source code itself is not in the app.

You can access the *values* of the constants defined in `R.java` programmatically. In fact, that is the point of the `R` class: give you values that you can use to identify resources. Every time your code has `R.layout.main` or `R.string.app_name` or `R.mipmap.ic_launcher`, you are programmatically referring to `R`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you mentioned "The source code itself is not in the app.": (1)  But I checked the path to R.java, and it was in the following path:C:\Users\aba\AndroidStudioProjects\Test-Notification-1\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\example\altenos\test_notification_1\R.java....my question is: since R.java are located inside ...\app\build\......\R.java..why I cant have access to it from Android Studio?

Comment: @LetsamrIt: Android Studio is not running on your Android device. It is running on Windows, macOS, or Linux. Most likely, the `build/` directory that you cite is not on your Android device. Most likely, it too is on Windows, macOS, or Linux. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `openFileInput()` are methods that you can call on Android, to access files on the Android device. Since `R.java` is not on the Android device, neither `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` nor `openFileInput()` will give you access to it.